# How did the hunter survive?

Tags: plot-explanation, 13-assassins

Spoilers below.

In the japanese movie *13 Assassin*s, the movie ends with everyone dead except for two people: Shinzaemon's nephew and the hunter that the samurai found in the woods. However, we were very explicitly shown the hunter taking a sword through the throat and being slashed in the belly just minutes earlier. While he addresses the belly wound by noting that he's been given worse by bears, he does not address his other wound. In fact, that wound seems to have mysteriously vanished.

**What happened to the hunter's seemingly fatal wound, and how did he survive it?**

Answer (score 2):

The international version of the [film strongly implies he is a demon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1436045/faq) (yokai) from Japanese mythology. Hence his supernatural toughness and rapid healing.

Comment: Yes. I would say he’s more of a spirit but same thing.

Comment: That was my best assumption, and it certainly follows a trope in anime/manga of having a supernatural character help people he/she/it is curious about. The hunter certainly expressed a lot of interest in samurai culture throughout his screen time.